# Bootstrap Typeahead using angular not displayed dynamic scope value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-typeahead, angular-ui-typeahead

Typeahead is working fine if scope assigned in static but Typeahead  is not displayed when "lists scope" is dynmaically change.

When user type in input box we calling `filterResponse()` and return the json to lists scope.

We use same lists scope in typeahead instance .

When i am print "lists" in expression of my page i am able to see returned value but typeahead is not dispalyed .

But when we statically assigned objects in "lists" scope typeahead is working

**JS:**

```
$scope.$watch('typedword',function(){
                   $scope.lists=filterResponse();


   },false);
```

**JSON(filterResponse())**

```
$scope.lists = {
    "count": 6,
    "brands": [{
        "number": 9,
        "brand": "aaaaa"
    }, {
        "number": 3,
        "brand": "project management"
    }, {
        "number": 2,
        "brand": "adasdadasd"
    }, {
        "number": 2,
        "brand": "gsdfgrtwetwert"
    }, {
        "number": 2,
        "brand": "dfghgdfghdfgh"
    }, {
        "number": 2,
        "brand": "dfghdfghrtr"
    }]
};
```

sdfsd

Comment: it's best if you can provide a fiddler and we can edit your code on that.

Comment: Perhaps you need to return promises instead?